# Drag and drop divs and store position

Tags: jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to make a drag and drop script but I'm stuck. What I want to achieve is: to drag elements from one side and put them inside a `div`. When I move the element inside that `div` my left and top position should be calculated from the edges of the droppable `div` not the entire document. So I can arrange and display dragged `div`s at the exact position even after refresh.
My question is how can I get the position of `div`s and make an ajax call to store them in database. Here is my code and jsfiddle:
**html**

```
<div data-id="1" class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <p>Drag me </p>
</div>
<div data-id="2" class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <p>Drag me </p>
</div>
<div data-id="3" class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <p>Drag me </p>
</div>
<div data-id="4" class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <p>Drag me</p>
</div>
<div  data-id="5" class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <p>Drag me </p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
<div id="pos"></div>
```

**js**

```
 $(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable
    (
    {
        drag: function(){
            var pos=$(this).attr('style');
            $("#pos").html(pos);
            }
    });
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
          
      }
    });
  });
```

**jsfiddle**
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8h0kyeoa/2/)

**edit**
I updated the code, managed to get the position of the `div` but it does not take it from the edge of the droppable `div` it takes the position from the entire document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i managed to make it working as it should, here is jsfiddle and jquery if someone else need this in future.
**jquery**

```
$(function() {
    var pos=null;
    var parent=null;
    var current=null;
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable
    (
    {
        drag: function(){
            pos = $(this).offset();
            parent = $( "#droppable" ).offset();
            current = {left: pos.left - parent.left, top: pos.top - parent.top };
            $("#pos").html( current.left + ', ' + current.top );

            }
    });
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
           $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "insert.php",
  data: { name: current.left, location: current.top }
})

      }

    });
  });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8h0kyeoa/4/)